# Why is the inner product of -1,+1 binary variables at most $n-2$ and not at most $n-1$?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, boolean-algebra

In short, if $x \neq u_i \in \{\pm1 \}^n$ then why is:

$$ \langle x, u_i \rangle \leq n-2 $$

but not:

$$ \langle x, u_i \rangle \leq n-1 $$

?

---

To add context:

I was reading [understanding machine learning from theory to algorithms](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf) and it had claim 20.1 section 20.3 on the section of the expressive power of Neural Networks. In the proof it said to consider "binary" vectors $\{ \pm 1 \}^n$ (which I will call Rademacher vectors). Let $f$ be a Boolean function and consider the Rademacher vectors that make $f$ output 1. If we consider some $x \in \{ \pm 1\}^n$ such that $u_i \neq x$ then they claim that:

$$ \langle x, u_i \rangle \leq n-2 $$

Which I think is false. Isn't the correct statement:

$$ \langle x, u_i \rangle \leq n-1 $$

The reason I think this is if $x \neq u_i$ then there exists at least **one** entry in the vector that are difference. Call it entry/index $j$. Thus $x[j] \neq u_i[j] \implies x[j]u_i[j] -1 $ since they must have opposite sign and both are entries in Rademacher vectors. Thus since we only need 1 entry for this to be true we get $-1$ instead of $-2$. In more detail an inner product is:

$$ \langle x, u_i \rangle = \sum^n_{j=1} x[j] u_i[j]$$

since there are n terms we are adding, if we have n agreements then we have a sum of n, but if we have a single disagreement then we have only a decrease of 1, right? Is that correct or am I missing something super dum?

Comment: You are replacing at least one +1 by a -1, the net effect is at least -2.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that if we have one disagreement then we change one single entry from +1 to -1. Thus, the summation decrease by 1 because we are missing one of the +1's in the summation but on top of that because they are Rademacher vectors instead of simple binary 0,1 then it means that the +1 actually changes to -1, meaning the inner product decreases by an additional 1.

So it decreases by 2 cuz:

1. we lose a +1 in the summation
2. but we also replace the +1 with a -1

so total decrease is by two leading to $ \leq n-2$